# How do I convert a dataframe row into a set of pairs?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in the follow format:

`df = pd.DataFrame([{'var1': 'a,b,c', },
                   {'var1': 'd,e,f,x,y',}])`

My ultimate goal convert each row into a series of pairs, with the first element in the row becoming the first element of the pairs, with every subsequent element appearing as the second member of the pair:

```
  var1 new_col
0    b       a
1    c       a
2    e       d
3    f       d
4    x       d
5    y       d
```

I can successfully get what I want with the following (probably very hacky code):

```
df.loc[:, 'new_col'] = df.var1.map(lambda x: x[0])**

reshaped = \
(df.set_index(df.columns.drop('var1',1).tolist())
   .var1.str.split(',', expand=True)
   .drop([0],axis=1)
   .stack()
   .reset_index()
   .rename(columns={0:'var1'})
   .loc[:, df.columns]
)
print(reshaped)
```

The problem comes when I try to apply it to my dataset, which uses full words:

```
    Folder
0   Land - General,Land - General
1   private,Water- air June 2019
2   private,Water- air June 2019
3   private,Water- air June 2019
```

Specifically, the problem seems to be when I apply `df.var1.map(lambda x: x[0])` . I end up getting the first letter instead of the entire instance of the word:

```
    Folder  new_col
0   Land - General,Land - General   L
1   private,Water- Air June 2019    p
2   private,Water- Air June 2019    p
3   private,Water- Air June 2019    p
```

How do I get my real dataset to work like my toy dataset?

** Apologies: I forgot this line, and only added it the next day.

Comment: I can't fully understand what you are doing, but if you are trying to get the first out of the `Land - General...` and `private,Water...`, you can simply use `df["Folder"].str.extract("(?P<new>\w+)")`.

Comment: When I was adding the code yesterday, I forgot a crucial line `df.loc[:, 'new_col'] = df.var1.map(lambda x: x[0])`.  Have added it now.  Apologies for the confusion.  I am working on your suggestion now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a brute force method like this - you can change the column as needed.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'var1': "private,public,protected", },
                   {'var1': "land,car,truck,train,cart",}])    
arr = []
for j in range(2):
    arr.append(pd.DataFrame([(c, df.iloc[j][0].split(',')[0]) for i,c in enumerate(df.iloc[j][0].split(',')) if i>0]))
pd.concat(arr)
```

This will result

```
    0           1
0   public      private
1   protected   private
0   car         land
1   truck       land
2   train       land
3   cart        land
```

Comment: This works - thank you.  In case it's helpful for anyone using this code at a later date: I had to substitute `range(2)` with `range(12412)` - 12412 is the number of rows in my original dataframe.   I also substituted every instance of `df` (but not `DataFrame`) with the name of my dataframe.  And I modified the last line, so my output was a dataframe: `df5 = pd.concat(arr)`.  Thank you again smishra.

Comment: Actually, instead of hardcoding it to 12412 you can do df.shape[0] that is number of rows in data frame - check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html

Comment: THANK YOU - that is super, super useful.